# Do you know any good source for human-robot interactions?

Tags: interaction-design, user-behavior, physical, human-interface-guideline

"In most cases, user experience design (UX or UXD or UED) fully encompasses traditional human-computer interaction (HCI) design, and extends it by addressing all aspects of a product or service as perceived by users."

In near future, I think that this area will be fruitful, especially for Robot assisted therapy related ones?

Is there any resource that is related to human-robot interaction for UX designers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of references available on the internet.

- [**Human robot interactions from the Interaction design foundation**](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-02675-6_14) : To quote a small part of the article

> Werry & Dautenhahn (2007) showed that an interactive, mobile robot
>   engages children with autism better than a non-robotic conventional
>   toy. A physician or physiotherapist may use robotic technology in
>   order to find out about the nature of a particular medical condition
>   or impairment, e.g. to find out about the nature of motor impairment
>   after stroke, and may use an assessment robot to be tested with both
>   healthy people and stroke patients. Similarly, a psychologist may
>   study the nature of autism by using robotic artefacts, comparing,e.g.
>   how children respond to social cues, speech or tactile interaction.
>   Such artifacts would be tools in the research on the nature of the
>   disorder or disability, rather than an assistive tool built to assist
>   the patients — which means it would also have to take into
>   consideration the patient's individual differences, likes and dislikes
>   and preferences in the context of using the tool.

- **[How User experience in  human-robot interaction change over time](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-02675-6_14)** : This is another interesting article which talks about how our experience changes with more interaction with robots over time. To quote the [abstract](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-02675-6_14#page-1)

> This paper describes a User Experience (UX) study on industrial robots
>   in the context of a semiconductor factory cleanroom. We accompanied
>   the deployment of a new robotic arm, without a safety fence, over one
>   and a half years. Within our study, we explored if there is a UX
>   difference between robots which have been used for more than 10 years
>   within a safety fence (type A robot) and a newly deployed robot
>   without fence (type B robot). Further, we investigated if the UX
>   ratings change over time. The departments of interest were the oven
>   (type A robots), the etching (type B robot), and the implantation
>   department (type B robot). To observe experience changes over time, a
>   UX questionnaire was developed and distributed to the operators at
>   three defined points in time within these departments. The first
>   survey was conducted one week after the deployment of robot B (n=23),
>   the second survey was deployed six months later (n=21), and the third
>   survey was distributed one and a half years later (n=23). Our results
>   show an increasing positive UX towards the newly deployed robots with
>   progressing time, which partly aligns with the UX ratings of the
>   robots in safety fences. However, this effect seems to fade after one
>   year. We further found that the UX ratings for all scales for the
>   established robots were stable at all three points in time

- [The robotics group in USC has some interesting projects on how robotics can assist in Human assistive technologies](http://robotics.usc.edu/interaction/?l=Research%3aProjects%3aoverview_ahri)
- I also recommend looking at t[his press post which talks about social robots](http://robotics.usc.edu/~agents/miscellaneous/media/TheSociableRobot.pdf) and their influence on humans in an assistive aspect.To quote an excerpt from the article

> Robots can also teach children with special needs how to play with one
>   an- other. If a child is touching the robot inappropriately-slapping,
>   say, instead of stroking-the robot may back away or emit a warning
>   beep to encourage the child to change his behavior. Then, as the child
>   begins to master interactive skills, the robot's behavior may become
>   increasingly unpredictable, preparing the child for dealing with
>   humans.
>
> Dautenhahn has noticed that autistic children playing with Kaspar may
>   also spontaneously begin interacting with their teachers. "One
>   withdrawn boy who never played with other children or his teacher
>   became very interested in Kaspar's eyes," she says. "He pointed to
>   Kaspar's eyes, then to his own, and then, smiling, to his teacher's
>   eyes. This was an invitation to share, and the boy and his teacher
>   played together."
>
> Children with physical disabilities, too, respond well to robots. In
>   three schools in Austria, PlayROB gives children with cerebral palsy
>   and other severe disabilities the chance to play independently.
>   Controlling the robot with a joystick, buttons, their mouths or even
>   just head movements, the chil- dren can direct it to build LEGO
>   structures and do additional activities that let them experience the
>   creative expression, spatial recognition and accomplishment that other
>   children get from playing

Other articles worth exploring are given below

- [Experimental Design for Human-Robot Interaction with
  Assistive Technology](http://www.cs.uml.edu/~holly/papers/tsui-yanco-HRI08-AT-wkshp.pdf)
- [Assistive Technologies and Children-Robot Interaction](http://www.cs.uml.edu/~holly/papers/tsui-yanco-HRI08-AT-wkshp.pdf)

Comment: [Georgia Tech](http://humanslab.ece.gatech.edu/humanslab/Home.html) has a lab looking at the area of research too.